# Find replace Element using Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I'm trying to search a tag and replace an element in some XML code. Here is my attempt:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parse('../../../lib/config/folder/config.xml')

for tag_type in dom.getElementsByTagName('tag_type'):
    tag_type.childNodes = [dom.createTextNode("Replacement Word")]

print tag_type
```

I'm running Python 2.4 so Element tree is not an option. Currently, I'm getting a response of:

```
<DOM Element: tag_type at 0x1c28a0e0>
```

Not sure why it isn't printing and not replacing.

Comment: ElementTree [can be downloaded](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) for Python 2.4. Grab your copy [here](http://effbot.org/downloads#elementtree), Python 1.5.2 (!) and newer are supported.

Comment: I can't download it. I'm stuck with what I got unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot just assign to `childNodes`. You must use the [DOM methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#objects-in-the-dom) to manipulate the tree.

Comment: That's exactly what `print tag_type` would print. What did you expect?

Comment: It helps us greatly if you post what the input and desired output looks like.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I was expecting it to print the element in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the [Node API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#node-objects) to remove and add nodes:

```
for tag_type in dom.getElementsByTagName('tag_type'):
    while tag_type.hasChildNodes():
        tag_type.removeChild(tag_type.firstChild)
    tag_type.appendChild(dom.createTextNode("Replacement Word"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xml = '''\
... <root>
...    <tag_type>
...       Foo
...       Bar
...    </tag_type>
... </root>
... '''
>>> dom = minidom.parseString(xml)
>>> for tag_type in dom.getElementsByTagName('tag_type'):
...     while tag_type.hasChildNodes():
...         tag_type.removeChild(tag_type.firstChild)
...     tag_type.appendChild(dom.createTextNode("Replacement Word"))
... 
<DOM Text node "'Replacemen'...">
>>> print dom.toxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>
   <tag_type>Replacement Word</tag_type>
</root>
```

Comment: How do I grab a file from another folder?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. Use a different filename when parsing the file?

Comment: When I try this method I get a bunch of errors. I think it's because my xml file is not in the same active folder as I'm running the script from. Do I need to set a PATH to look in another folder for the xml file?

Comment: @AwayFromMyDesk: What **kind** of errors are you getting? And how are you parsing the file? Note that I used `parseString()` in my sample code because I had the XML in a string value. Use `.parse()` if you have a filename instead.

Comment: I was getting a bunch of errors internal to parseString() at lines 1925, 942, 223. Obviously not in my script. I put it back to just parse() now I'm just getting an error: NameError: name 'appendChild' is not defined

Comment: Then you didn't apply my code correctly. `appendChild()` is not a function but a method on the `tag_type` object. A `NameError` implies you are calling it as a function instead.

Comment: Yep, I put a equals sign instead of a '.' operator. Thanks so much. I had been trying to solve this problem sans help for a few days and clearly didn't get to far. Thanks again.