# Python read all elements in XAML file and replace some values

Tags: python, xml

So i have `XML` file, inside the file i have many `elements` like this:

```
<name search = "read TTT: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
```

So in each element i need to find this `search = "read TTT: write"` line and in case this `read TTT: write` start with `read` i need to change it (replace the read with another string).

What is the best\fastest way to do that ?

**Update**

So in case i have `element` like this (the word 'read' exist):

```
<name search = "read TTT: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
```

I want to replace it with this one (i only replace the read):

```
<name search = "NewValue TTT: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find replace Element using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189979/find-replace-element-using-python)

Comment: The string you want to replace with is always the same?

Comment: user @Alderven : no, this line: read TTT: write start here with read, so all the elements that name start with read i want to replace

Comment: Could you please add expected XML sample?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: @falukky see if the answer I posted, helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `minidom`:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml)

tags = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("name")
firstchild = tags[0]
firstchild.attributes["search"].value = 'NewValue TTT: write'

print(xmldoc.toxml())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><name search="NewValue TTT: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
```

**EDIT**:

For multiple tags, simply loop over:

```
xml = '''\
<root>
<name search = "read TTT: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>

<name search = "read2 TTT: write">
    <version id = "2.0.0">
        <value>myVal_2</value>
        <method>myMethod_2</method>
    </version>
</name>
</root>'''

from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml)

tags = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("name")

for item in tags:
    item.attributes["search"].value = 'NewValue TTT: write'

print(xmldoc.toxml())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>
<name search="NewValue TTT: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>

<name search="NewValue TTT: write">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal_2</value>
        <method>myMethod_2</method>
    </version>
</name>
</root>
```

Using `beautifulsoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''\
<root>
<name search = "read TTT: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>

<name search = "read TTT: write">
    <version id = "2.0.0">
        <value>myVal_2</value>
        <method>myMethod_2</method>
    </version>
</name>
</root>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml , 'lxml')
newVal = "NewValue"

for elem in soup.find_all("name"):
    elem['search'] = elem['search'].replace(str(elem['search']).split(" ")[0], newVal)        
   print(elem)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<name search="NewValue TTT: write">
<version id="1.0.0">
<value>myVal</value>
<method>myMethod</method>
</version>
</name>
<name search="NewValue TTT: write">
<version id="2.0.0">
<value>myVal_2</value>
<method>myMethod_2</method>
</version>
</name>
```

Comment: Thats works but, any way to add this new name elements to the xml file instead of edit the old ones ? (keep the old and add the new)

Comment: @falukky ofcourse create a new dom element or an empty xml file using beautiful soup and append these to it. This will go outside the current asked question. I suggest you ask a new question with your attempts shown. PS. If this answer helped you may accept it. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse #minidom does the trick
dom = parse('my_file.xml') #read in your file
res = dom.getElementsByTagName('name') #fetch the desired elements in the tree
for element in res: #loop through all 
    if element.getAttribute('search') == 'read TTT: write': #filter for the attribute and value
        element.setAttribute('search', 'New Value TTT: write') #in case of match, replace
with open('my_file_updated.xml','w') as f: #store the file
    f.write(dom.toxml())
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to add this new name elements to the xml file instead of edit the old ones ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <body>
            <name search = "read TTT: write">
                <version id = "1.0.0">
                    <value>myVal</value>
                    <method>myMethod</method>
                </version>
            </name>
            <name search = "read TTT: write">
                <version id = "1.0.0">
                    <value>myVal</value>
                    <method>myMethod</method>
                </version>
            </name>
        </body>
        """

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
sh = tree.findall('name')
for name in sh:
    val = name.get("search")
    if str(val) == "read TTT: write":
        name.set('search', 'NewValue TTT: write')


print (ET.tostring(tree))
```

Output:

```
   <body>
        <name search = "NewValue TTT: write">
            <version id = "1.0.0">
                <value>myVal</value>
                <method>myMethod</method>
            </version>
        </name>
        <name search = "NewValue TTT: write">
            <version id = "1.0.0">
                <value>myVal</value>
                <method>myMethod</method>
            </version>
         </name>
    </body>
```

Comment: This print only the first name element and my XML have mane name elements